# Compare UK EndDate with UTC current time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

How do I convert UK `endDate` to UTC so that I can compare with UTC current time (`nowTime`) on node? or is it better to do it other way around? convert current UTC time to London timezone and then do a comparison with UK `endDate`

For example:

```
const nowTime = new Date('Thu May 10 2020 15:55'); //mock now time in UTC

const date = { //this is london date/time
  EndDate: "2020-05-10",
  EndTime: "15:57",
}

const combineDateTime = date.EndDate + " " + date.EndTime;
const endDate = new Date(combineDateTime).getTime();

if (nowTime >= endDate) {
  console.log('expired');
} else {
  console.log('not expired')
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate how do you the comparison to be date only? time only?  and what is your desired output?

Comment: comparison with date and time from nowTime and Endate. `nowTime > endDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your local time is UK time this should work othewise you will have to count for the dls

```
 var now = new Date();
var nowTime = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds(), now.getUTCMilliseconds());
console.log('UTC (in ms): ' + nowTime.getTime())
nowTimeUTC=nowTime.getTime()

const date = { //this is london date/time via API response
  EndDate: "2020-06-12",
  EndTime: "00:12",
}

servertime=new Date(date.EndDate.concat(" "+date.EndTime))
servertimeinmill=servertime.getTime()
utcoffset=(servertime.getTimezoneOffset()/60)*60*60*1000
servetimeinUTC=servertimeinmill+utcoffset
console.log(servetimeinUTC)
console.log(nowTime>servetimeinUTC)
```

Comment: Thank you., that seem to work. Any reason why it can't be done using toLocaleString with timezone?

Comment: it can be done with `toLocaleString` however i don't recommend using it in this scenario because it is meant to be for representing time taking into concideration the language you choose as a parameter and this can cause a big problem because  `LocaleString('en-US') ` will show time in am/pm  ex: 01:00 pm but if you pick the parameter to ('it,IT) it will output a string representation as 13:00 this can cause a prob in simple time caluclation but it shouldn't be a problem if you calculate time in milliseconds

Comment: if my answer helped in anyway I will appreciate considering upvoting and accepting my answer

Comment: it didn't work actually. if you change nowTime to `new Date().getTime();` and EndTime to 22:30 - it shoud return false. server machine in utc.

Comment: are you sure that new Date().getTime() gives you time in milliseconds in UTC can you console.log it and tell me what it gives you?

Comment: your local machine will be your London timezone but on the server, it will always be UTC.  So you test it you should put `process.env.TZ = 'UTC'` at the top of your file.

Comment: console.log(new Date()) = 2020-06-11T21:14:36.633Z

Comment: It will always give you true because I used the date you provided in your example which is last month 2020-05-11 but if you change it to the 2020-05-11 although i made a mistake calculating the time offset i have updated that part though

Comment: Sorry your code does not work when `new Date().getTime();` are in UTC.

Comment: I have tested it it works on my end here is the code tested on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/tvfsnkcj/)  shows that it is working it won't work only if you nowtime is not on UTC

Comment: the time i put on jsfiddle for nowTime is in UTC in milliseconds you can check that online

Comment: i have updated my code it should work now i found what was causing the wrong values [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/h9nsjw7r/)

Comment: Thank you, does it handle Daylight saving time too?

Comment: it turns out the getTimezoneOffset() returns the time difference between local time and utc but if the localtime is behind utc the output is a positive number otherwise it will return a negative number hence why the subtract becomes an addition

Comment: i think it should because now in the UK it dls and hence why i used the getTimezoneOffset, so when time returns to usual that should be 0 as GMT is same as UTC (time)

Answer (score 1):

Since you also tagged `momentjs`, this is the alternative solution with [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

```
const expired = moment.tz('2020-05-10 15:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm', 'Europe/London').isSameOrBefore('2020-05-10T15:55:00.000Z')
```

For the actual `now` time, you can omit the date string

```
const expired = moment.tz('2020-05-10 15:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm', 'Europe/London').isSameOrBefore()
```

Or if you want semantically equivalent to `nowTime >= endDate`

```
const expired = moment().isSameOrAfter(moment.tz('2020-05-10 15:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm', 'Europe/London'))
```

Note that for `now`, we don't need to pass the timezone explicitly. But if you want an object with `UTC` timezone you can use

```
const nowInUTC = moment.utc()
```

Comment: Thank you, what the difference between this and Sven.hig answer?

Comment: My solution requires another library, if you don't mind another dependency, using `moment-timezone` makes it more readable and it automatically calculate Daylight Saving Time